# Baby Cry Sound detection

Tags: fft, sound-recognition

I wanted to write a code to detect baby cry sound.
I am using Windows as platform.  Presently, I am able to get audio samples and its frequency plot(using FFT) but not sure how to proceed forward.

I wanted to ask what steps I should follow to detect the baby cry sound given its time-frequency plot.

I saw some methods such as median filter followed by HMM in speech recognition. But for simple sound detection do I need to go for such sophiticated method?

I will be very grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This paper might have exactly what you need if you go the supervised learning route, it has a good comparison of logistical regressions versus convoluted nets

http://www.ieee.org.il/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/2016_ICSEE_paper_206.pdf

> In  this  work,  two  machine-learning  algorithms  were  pro-
>   posed  for  the  detection  of  baby  cry  in  audio  recordings:
>   a  logistic  regression  classifier  and  a  more  complex  CNN
>   classifier.  The  results  show  a  considerable  advantage  of  the
>   CNN  classifier  compared  to  the  logistic  regression  classifier.
>   As  CNNs  are  naturally  suited  for  large  training  datasets  and
>   for multi-class classification, we plan to train a CNN classifier
>   to detect various types of domestic sounds in addition to cry
>   signals.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it! , seems this will give good acccuracy. I have left the project though.

Comment: Good luck on your next endeavour! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have frequency bucket information, you essentially have a frequency histogram.

If you treat histograms as n dimensional vectors, you can use dot product to get a similarity value that goes from 0 to 1 and could tune that so that sounds that have a value greater than say 0.6 are considered a match.

For more information check this out:  http://blog.demofox.org/2015/02/13/writing-a-basic-search-engine-aka-calculating-similarity-of-histograms-with-dot-product/

Alternately you could get a little more advanced and use support vector machines, which require training data of both negatives and positives to find a way to differentiate hits and misses.

Comment: If you want to detect when the baby is crying as opposed to sleeping, I would go with a band-pass filter in the frequency region corresponding to baby cries (near 500-5000Hz I guess) and set a threshold. Basically what Alan is proposing. Speech recognition seems overcomplicated for your use case. SR is required to figure out intelligible **words**, not featureless cries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :). I know the frequency region corresponding to baby cries is near 500-5000Hz. But it shows lot of variation for different baby sounds. So how to proceed. Also what do you mean by "set a threshold"?

Comment: By setting a threshold I believe he meant to basically watch for a frequency amplitude to go over a specific value.

Comment: Have you noticed a specific "shape" of frequency amplitudes (harmonics) for crying versus other baby sounds? If so, the histogram dot product technique can help you distinguish the crying case from the other cases. If you haven't noticed any such pattern, support vector machines can be used to find any such non obvious patterns.

Comment: Wait! Frequency amplitude should directly be proportional to the sound intensity, right?

Comment: Yes, but your ears don't work linearly, that's why there is db (:  you could normalize the sound samples if you wanted to focus on the shape instead of the volume, but probably want to ignore anything that is too quiet.