# Blow sound recognition without using machine learning

Tags: fft, audio, sound-recognition

I am building an experience in Unity that will recognize when a user blows into the microphone. I have a working implementation that recognizes sounds above a certain loudness threshold, but I want to take it a step further and identify only blow sounds.

**My current implementation is:**

I extract FFT information from a 1-second sound clip and identify the range of frequencies involved. The idea is that the blowing sound covers a larger number of frequencies than typical speech (based on its spectrogram), so I expected its frequency range to be close to 100%. This implementation picks up other sounds and speech that have a frequency range close to 100%, which I guess is to be expected, but that's what I have so far.

As you can see in the spectrogram, it's easy to see where the blowing sound occurs. While speech appears more jagged, the blowing sound seems to have a very consistent pattern. [image: Spectogram of speech and blowing sound.]

**Research that I have done:**

- I tried to follow the steps in [this academic research paper](https://www.etsmtl.ca/ETS/media/ImagesETS/Labo/LIVIA/Publications/2013/Carbonneau_NEWCAS_2013.pdf) first. While I learned a lot about digital sound, I also realized it was relying on machine learning, and I want to avoid that.
- I analyzed the spectrogram above and semi-successfully implemented sound recognition based on the frequency range for a 1-second sound clip. I used FFT information for this implementation.
- I tried to treat a frequency histogram of my audio sample as an n-dimensional vector. I calculated the dot product of an audio sample and a pre-recorded blowing sound based on one of the answers from [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24648/baby-cry-sound-detection). The results were inconsistent, so I abandoned the idea.
- I found a [question that seemed the most similar](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/44597/when-does-the-laugh-track-kick-in) for my situation. The comments helped me solidify my belief that machine learning would be an overkill for this situation. The answers seem to suggest classification algorithms as a solution, and, if I'm not mistaken, that's machine learning. (Correct me if I'm wrong though)

**My question is:**

Which other audio features can I extract from the audio clip/FFT to identify a blowing sound more precisely?

I can visually see the blowing sound in the spectrogram, which leads me to believe it's possible to identify it with an algorithm without using machine learning.

I am relatively new to sound processing, so any information is highly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend [synchrosqueezing](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy) for inspection and [scattering](https://github.com/kymatio/kymatio) for classification.

Comment: Thank you @OverLordGoldDragon! Just to clarify, is scattering a machine learning technique?

Comment: It's inspired by convolutions and greatly improves performance in absence of big data; main difference is filters are pre-designed and fixed, but we can stack learned layers (e.g. conv) on top. Helpful [lecture](https://youtu.be/4eyUReyIPXg).

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you so much, I will check out the lecture.

Comment: I misread the question as _"with"_; in the _without_ case you can use extracted scattering features with pattern matching algorithms (if you know the pattern) - though minimally, a one-layer SVM would be simpler (and likely more effective). Regardless I'd wait for others' responses, many options here.

Comment: To distinguish speech from stochastic noise-like blow sounds, a basic approach like computing the [spectral flatness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_flatness) in a blockwise manner could potentially be a promising first attempt.

Comment: @applesoup thank you, that does sound promising! I implemented spectral flatness calculation based on FFT like in this link: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2016/05/03/spectral-flatness. However, as long as one of the values in FFT is 0 (which is always the case), the spectral flatness is always 0. Do you have any suggestions on either improving the spectral flatness calculation or using another similar feature?

Comment: I'd start by excluding any zero bins from the calculation. Alternatively, you could add a very small nonzero value to those bins.

Comment: I'm wondering, however, why (at least?) one of the DFT bins is always zero. To find out more: is it always the same bin(s) that's zero?

Comment: Sounds good, I'll try that.

The reason why at least one of the FFT bins is always zero is because of the code I'm using. It apparently spits out some 0 values because of garbage collection or something. I am using the code from here - https://answers.unity.com/questions/974565/how-to-do-a-fft-in-unity.html

I actually thought that was normal until you pointed it out, so thanks for catching that!

Comment: And no, it's not the same bins that are zero. They vary.